# ActionListener on JButton creating "image" of a button in my frame?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am creating a game of connect-4 using swing in java.
I have an array of 6 buttons which are used to input the move the player wants to make.

When I click a button, the ActionListener does what I want it to do, but also places an image of the most recently pressed button in the upper left of the screen. I say "image" of a button because it cannot be clicked. Here's my code:

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    ArrayList<JButton> buttonList;

    public ButtonPanel(){

        //set up the JPanel...

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            buttonList.add(new JButton("" + i));
            buttonList.get(i).addActionListener(this);
            add(buttonList.get(i));
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (JButton b : buttonList){
            if(e.getSource() == b){
                frame.playerMove =  buttonList.indexOf(e.getSource());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's what happens when I click the button 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvmWZ.png)

[And when I click button 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPoeQ.png)

Does anybody know what's happening here, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but also places an image of the most recently pressed button in the upper left of the screen. I say "image" of a button because it cannot be clicked.

Sounds to me like you are doing custom painting.

1. Make sure you are overriding `paintComponent()`, not paint();
2. Make sure the first statement in the paintComponent() method is `super.paintComponent(...)` so the background of your panel is cleared before the custom painting is done.

If this doesn't help, then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

In the future, make sure you post a SSCCE with all your questions.

Comment: You are correct, I was overriding `paint()` instead of `paintComponent()` and my code now works. Thanks for the fast response :)